# Dropdown box populating (I think), but not displaying for Angular UI typeahead

Tags: html, css, angularjs, meanjs, angular-ui-typeahead

I've spent a day trying to figure out what's going on with my typeahead dropdown, but I'm just not getting it.

Here's an image from the app (http://julieknowles.azurewebsites.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/search5.png).  Here's the start of of my Angular view html:

```
<div class="container" data-ng-controller="HeaderController">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button class="navbar-toggle" type="button" data-ng-click="toggleCollapsibleMenu()">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a href="/#!/" class="navbar-brand"><i class="fa fa-beer"></i> On Tapp</a>
    </div>
    <nav class="collapse navbar-collapse" collapse="!isCollapsed" role="navigation">

        <ul class="nav navbar-nav" data-ng-if="menu.shouldRender(authentication.user);">
      <li><a href="#!/nearby"><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i> Nearby</a></li>
      <li><a href="#!/ratings"><i class="fa fa-star"></i> Ratings</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://green-brass-doberman.github.io/on-tapp/" target="blank"><i class="fa fa-users"></i> About</a></li>

      <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" action="#" role="search">
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" data-ng-model="selected" data-typeahead="name as name.name for name in beersAndBreweries | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:8" class="form-control ta-search" id="navbarInput-01" placeholder="Search for beers or breweries">
            <span class="input-group-btn">
              <button type="submit" class="btn"><span class="fui-search"></span></button>
            </span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
```

And the start of the JS for the controller:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('core').controller('HeaderController', ['$scope', 'Authentication', 'Menus', 'allBeers', 'allBreweries',
    function($scope, Authentication, Menus, allBeers, allBreweries) {
        $scope.authentication = Authentication;
        $scope.isCollapsed = false;
        $scope.menu = Menus.getMenu('topbar');

        $scope.selected = '';
        var saveData = [];

    $scope.beersAndBreweries = [];
    var handleBeerSuccess = function(data, status){
      //$scope.allBeers = data.data;
      saveData = data.data;
      for (var j=0; j<saveData.length; j++) {
        $scope.beersAndBreweries.push({name: saveData[j].name, type: 'beer', id: saveData[j].id});
      }
    };
    // send the brewery id
    allBeers.getData('mtUjck').success(handleBeerSuccess);

    $scope.coords = {lat:37.7833, long:-122.4167};
    var handleBrewerySuccess = function(data, status){
      //$scope.allBreweries = data.data;
      saveData = data.data;
      for (var j=0; j<saveData.length; j++) {
        $scope.beersAndBreweries.push({name: saveData[j].brewery.name, type: 'brewery', id: saveData[j].breweryId});
      }
    };
    allBreweries.getData($scope.coords).success(handleBrewerySuccess);
```

You can see that it's pulling the data from the typeahead and it "appears" to be loaded correctly, but it's not displaying the dropdown.  I've messed with the CSS by changing colors, background, z-indexes and other styles.  I've moved the typeahead to different areas.  I've created a plunkr (plnkr.co/OhFFupoxNsbuO9sjPSOy).  Here's the html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="plunker">
  <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.5/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.4.0.js"></script>
    <script src="example.js"></script>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
<div class='container-fluid' ng-controller="TypeaheadCtrl">
    <p></p>
    <b>Selected Beer/Brewery:</b>
    <blockquote>
      ID: {{selected.id}}<br/>
      Name: {{selected.name}}<br/>
      Type: {{selected.type}}
    </blockquote>
    Enter a name: <input type="text" ng-model="selected" typeahead="name as name.name for name in beersAndBreweries | filter:$viewValue" />
</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

and here's the JS:

```
angular.module('plunker', ['ui.bootstrap']);
function TypeaheadCtrl($scope) {

  $scope.selected = "";
  $scope.beersAndBreweries = [
    {'id': 'BBw7o7', 'name': 'Pacific Brewing Laboratory', 'type': 'brewery'}, 
    {'id': 'kSUGO5', 'name': 'Cellarmaker Brewing Company', 'type': 'brewery'},
    {'id': 'Dcwb2m', 'name': 'Big Bang Brewery', 'type': 'brewery'},
    {'id': 'QeR22V', 'name': 'Mateveza Yerba Mate Ale', 'type': 'brewery'},
    {'id': 'FPNwB5', 'name': '21st Anniversary Ale', 'type': 'beer'},
    {'id': '3MS5k0', 'name': 'Barrel-Aged Vanilla Bean Wreck Alley', 'type': 'beer'},
    {'id': 'CPHfHh', 'name': 'Mosaic Session Ale', 'type': 'beer'}
  ];
}
```

I'll keep playing around with it and trying to figure it out, but any help would be appreciated!  Thanks!

EDIT:  I'm thinking it has something to do with this dropdown box showing up, but I'm not sure where it's coming from!  (http://julieknowles.azurewebsites.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/search9.png)

Comment: give us CSS please :)

Comment: The plunker is working as expected, or have I misunderstood?

Comment: Yes, I have the same comment. plunker works fine

Comment: Yes the plunkr works...it's my code that wasn't working.  I've actually taken a different route and not using the typeahead anyway because I don't have a way to get all the data for the typeahead easily.  Thanks everyone for looking!